# Creating a new column and filling Boolean values in - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset, which looks like the below:

```html
A  B C  Location 
10 15 15 South 
11 12 42 North
20 13 36 South 
15 30 40 West
10 40 20 East
15 20 10 South 
45 45 23 North 
12 12 12 West 
2 0 1 East
```

I want to create a new column which print True or false based on the condition if A and B and C <=16.

I have tried doing:

```py
for rows in df.rows:

df['Purity'] = np.where((A <= 16 and B<=16 and C<=16), 'True', 'False')
```

But this does not fill up for each row cell as a separate value but it fill the first value in all the cells of the column.

I would like to have the result as:

```html
A  B C   Location  Purity 
10 15 15 South  TRUE
11 12 42 North FALSE
20 13 36 South  FALSE
15 30 40 West FALSE
10 40 20 East FALSE
15 20 10 South  FALSE
45 45 23 North  FALSE
12 12 12 West  TRUE
2 0 1 East  TRUE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` for bitwise AND with parantheses if need set new strings values by conditions:

```
df['Purity'] = np.where((df.A <= 16) & (df.B<=16) & (df.C<=16), 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```

---

If want set boolean True and False values set chained masks:

```
df['Purity'] = (df.A <= 16) & (df.B<=16) & (df.C<=16)
```

What is same like:

```
df['Purity'] = np.where((df.A <= 16) & (df.B<=16) & (df.C<=16), True, False)
```

Another idea is compare all columns together and use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) if all `True`s per rows:

```
df['Purity'] = (df[['A','B','C']] <= 16).all(axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi, Still with all these solutions, the problem is the same. It either prints True or False for every cell in that column. It just picks the first solution and fills the whole column with that value (True OR False)